# Possible to change the visibility of a column in finder with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

When I change the `visible` property of a Finder column to `false` it does not have any effect even after closing and reopening the window.

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set visible of column id kind column of list view options of Finder window 1 to false
end tell
```

It appears to be a bug. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe it's a *bug* because if you look at the **AppleScript Dictionary** for **Finder**, it shows the following for `list view options` as a *property*:

- **list view options** (list view options, r/o) : the list view options for the container window

The user cannot change a *read only property*, however there is a **UI Scripting** solution.

That said, I try to avoid **UI Scripting** whenever possible however, I have the daily need to open an external drive in a particular view, sorted by size and to do this a **UI Scripting** solution was this only choice I could find.

I've taken the relevant *example* **AppleScript** *code* from it to toggle the visibility of the **Kind** column:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if (current view of front Finder window) is equal to list view then
        activate
        my toggleCheckBox("Kind")
    end if
end tell

to toggleCheckBox(thisBox)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "j" using command down
        tell window 1 of application process "Finder"
            click checkbox thisBox of group 1
            click button 2
        end tell
    end tell
end toggleCheckBox
```

Note that this particular **UI Scripting** solution does open and close the **View Options** for the front **Finder** window and is a bit of a visual distraction and one of the reasons I dislike **UI Scripting** however, sometimes one has no other choice to accomplish a given task. Note that I'm not saying it cannot be done any other way, just at the present time I don't know another way.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [`try`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [`error`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html) *statement* in the **[AppleScript Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10)**. See also [Working with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, UI Scripting may require the use of the [`delay`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* as appropriate, needed or wanted.

Comment: OK, thanks. I picked up from tips looking at this. BTW, the code I listed in my OP was basically generated by the recording feature. So I'm not sure why that shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution over here: https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=184412#p184412